# I get error property name when press upload Button?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 project  I face issue I get error Property Name when upload data .

I choose file first then after that press button Upload

after press button upload I get this error below :

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  
    at UploadComponent.uploadFile (upload.component.ts:96)  
    at UploadComponent_Template_button_click_5_listener (upload.component.html:6)  
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14286)  
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14321)  
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)  
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)  
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27394)  
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)  
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)  
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
```

I get this error on line below :

```
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
```

full uplod code

component.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">  
   <input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file"  multiple>  
     
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadFile(file)">Upload File</button>  
 </div>
```

component.ts

```
public uploadFile = (files) => {  
    if (files.length === 0) {  
      return;  
    }  
  
    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];  
    const formData = new FormData();  
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);  
      
    this.http.post('https://localhost:44396/api/ApprovalQuality/', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})  
      .subscribe(event => {  
          
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)  
        {  
         
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);  
        }  
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {  
          this.message = 'Upload success.';  
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);  
        }  
      });  
  }
```

so How to solve this error please ?

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(fileToUpload)` inside `uploadFile()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..

```
<div class="col-md-3">  
   <input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file"  multiple>  
     
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="file.click()">Upload File</button>  
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for reply I need to get file from  path selected by choose file

Comment: I need when press button upload get file selected by choose file .solution above make to me repeated same action two time meaning i will select file two time and i don't need that

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you haven't get the value of `'#file'`. That's why you got `'fileToUpload'` undefined, and of course this

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Try this:

- First, declare a @viewchild:

> `@viewchild('file') uploadFile: ElementRef`;

- Then use nativeElement (It's like document.getElementById in HTML DOM) to get file from `<input>`:

  let file = this.uploadFile.nativeElement.value;

EDIT:

declare viewchild:

```
@ViewChild('file') someFile: ElementRef | undefined;
```

uploadFile function:

```
public uploadFile(): void {
    let files = this.someFile.nativeElement.value;  
    if (files || files.length === 0) {  
      return;  
    }  
    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];  
    const formData = new FormData();  
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);  
      
    this.http.post('https://localhost:44396/api/ApprovalQuality/', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})  
      .subscribe(event => {  
          
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)  
        {  
         
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);  
        }  
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {  
          this.message = 'Upload success.';  
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);  
        }  
      });  
  }
```

Comment: it give me duplicate identifier Uploadfile

Comment: also where i assign let file = this.uploadFile.nativeElement.value;

Comment: also on html what must declare

Comment: can you please give me more details component.html and component.ts

Comment: @ahmedbarbary so change 'uploadFile' identifier to something you haven't use and about the HTML you already declare #file in your HTML so you don't need to fix it

Comment: where declare file let file = this.uploadFile.nativeElement.value;

Comment: can you please show me component.html and component.ts code if possibel will be

Comment: @ahmedbarbary your HTML is okay, problem is in uploadFile(), I edited my answer

Comment: @ahmedbarbary '@viewchild' is declare in component.ts, in where you declare your public variables

Comment: and what html component must be

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">  
   <input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file"  multiple>  
     
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadFile(file)">Upload File</button>  
 </div>

Comment: like this, use your previous html component, It's fine

Comment: it give me error failed to execute  append on form data : parameter 2 is not type of blob

Comment: I'm currently can't give you a good example code, sorry for that but understand this

Comment: formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name); 
the problem is in fileToUpload, you need fileToUpload type is blob. when you upload file to server, you are sending a blob (or a byte array, it's kinda same thing). You need to convert (or cast) fileUpload to a blob then append it like your original code

Comment: when make let fileToUpload:Blob = <File>files[0];  give me error Property Name not exist per type Blob

Comment: formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);   ON this line it give me Name not exist per type Blob